# How to create a custom file type that holds text and images?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsimage

I know this is going to be somewhat hard to answer, but I need to save text and images into a single file (like photoshop does). Should I make a custom file type, or is there another way to do this?

If I need a custom file type, would somebody please give me link to something that may help me make the file type store the data properly? If there is another way, how can I do this?

NOTE: I am using this in a application that imports three images, and lets users put text over them, so I may not be able to get the information needed to store the images as text in any way. If it is what I have to do, I will need a link to some helpful information.

Comment: Could you describe your data's arrangement? Are the images in `NSImage` objects that are in an array, for example? Are you using an `NSDocument` subclass?  When you say "import three images", these are three arbitrary images chosen by the user? Also, are you trying to make a new _image_ file that can be opened by other applications, or just store the work that your user does so that _your_ application can open it again?

Comment: I will update this tomarrow, then. Thanks for telling me that more information is needed.

Comment: You don't need anything fancy; there's just a couple of different possibilities here and it will be easiest to give good advice with a bit more detail.

Comment: I have gotten my answer, so I won't bother rewriting this unless someone wants me to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to save objects to a file is to add them to an `NSDictionary` and then use `NSArchiver` to archive the dictionary into data.

For example in a document based app:

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    if ([typeName isEqualToString:@"YourTypeName"]) {
          //Create a Dictionary
          NSMutableDictionary *dictToSave = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
          //Add the first image to the dictionary
          [dictToSave setObject:image1 forKey:@"Image1"];
          //Add the first image's text
          [dictToSave setObject:image1text forKey:@"Image1Text"];
          //etc.
          [dictToSave setObject:image2 forKey:@"Image2"];
          [dictToSave setObject:image2text forKey:@"Image2Text"];              
          [dictToSave setObject:image3 forKey:@"Image3"];
          [dictToSave setObject:image3text forKey:@"Image3Text"];
          //Return the archived data
          return [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictToSave];
    }
    //Don't generate an error
    outError = NULL;
    return nil;
}
```

To read this data, just unarchive the dictionary and set the objects:

```
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName
error:(NSError **)outError {
    if ([typeName isEqualToString:@"MyTypeName"]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *readDict = 
        [NSUnarchiver unarchiveRootObjectWithData:data];
        image1 = [readDict objectForKey:@"Image1"];
        image1text = [readDict objectForKey:@"Image1Text"];
        image2 = [readDict objectForKey:@"Image2"];
        image2text = [readDict objectForKey:@"Image2Text"];
        image3 = [readDict objectForKey:@"Image3"];
        image3text = [readDict objectForKey:@"Image3Text"];
    }
    outError = NULL;
    return YES;
}
```

You will also need to define your custom file type in your app's plist file.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that as soon as I can get to my computer.

Comment: While you are on the right track, the code you posted, as it is now, has numerous problems. `NSMutableDictionary *dictToSave;  //Create a Dictionary` does not create a dictionary, it only defines it. The following lines will likely crash as you are trying to send messages to an undefined object. The `unimpErr` (unimplemented error) stuff can likely be removed, as it's only meant as placeholder code until you've implemented your own code, which is what the code above that does.

Comment: I know how to work around that stuff. Thanks a lot, @NSGod and @spudwaffle.